# Trigger - AFTER INSERT - GIVING syntax error

Tags: php, triggers, insert

```
CREATE TRIGGER giveaccess AFTER INSERT ON `befree_user`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user_access(user_id) VALUES (NEW.user_id);
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define another delimiter than `;`

```
delimiter |

   CREATE TRIGGER giveaccess AFTER INSERT ON `befree_user`
   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
         INSERT INTO user_access(user_id) VALUES (NEW.user_id);
   END;

|
delimiter ;
```

If not the DB thinks that after the first `;` the statement is done and will throw an error.